# Dictionary (of integer,class) type

Tags: vb.net, class, dictionary

I would like to save variables in a simple method before adding to a datatable. Is it possible to have a `dictionary (of integer,class)` type like the code below? I can then loop through the keys to get the variables.Any ideas please?

```
     Public Class CONTACTS
        Dim FIRST_NAME As String
        Dim SURNAME As String
        Dim DOB As Date
        Dim AGE As Integer
    End Class


    Sub TEST_DICT()

        Dim dctCONTACTS As Dictionary(Of Integer, List OF Class(CONTACTS))  'not sure how to declare this

        dctCONTACTS.Add(1, "MARK").FIRST_NAME  'not sure how to savevariable
        dctCONTACTS.Add(1, "SMITH").SURNAME
        dctCONTACTS.Add(1, "5 May 1995").DOB
        dctCONTACTS.Add(1, 31).AGE

        dctCONTACTS.Add(2, "ANNE").FIRST_NAME
        dctCONTACTS.Add(2, "MOORE").SURNAME
        dctCONTACTS.Add(3, "5 April 1990").DOB
        dctCONTACTS.Add(4, 26).AGE

        Dim X = dctCONTACTS(1).AGE
    End Sub
```

Comment: What does the integer represent?  A `List(of Contacts)` would probably do fine all alone

Comment: `before adding to a datatable` it should be noted that the DataTable cab be a perfectly usable container.  You dont *have* to store data elsewhere unless it is incomplete needs additional massaging before it can be saved.

Comment: tks Plutonix, easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really you go look at the many many "how to code VB.NET" resources online rather than ask basic syntax questions here.

Here is your code in valid VB.NET:

```
 Public Class CONTACTS
    Public FIRST_NAME As String
    Public SURNAME As String
    Public DOB As Date
    Public AGE As Integer
End Class

Sub TEST_DICT()

    Dim dctCONTACTS As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of CONTACTS)) 

    dctCONTACTS.Add(1, New List(Of CONTACTS) From
    {
        New CONTACTS() With { .FIRST_NAME = "MARK", .SURNAME = "SMITH", .DOB = New DateTime(1995, 5, 5), .AGE = 31 },
        New CONTACTS() With { .FIRST_NAME = "JOE", .SURNAME = "SMITH", .DOB = New DateTime(1995, 5, 5), .AGE = 31 },
        New CONTACTS() With { .FIRST_NAME = "SARAH", .SURNAME = "SMITH", .DOB = New DateTime(1995, 5, 5), .AGE = 31 }
    })

    dctCONTACTS.Add(2, New List(Of CONTACTS) From
    {
        New CONTACTS() With { .FIRST_NAME = "BOB", .SURNAME = "SMITH", .DOB = New DateTime(1995, 5, 5), .AGE = 31 },
        New CONTACTS() With { .FIRST_NAME = "SUE", .SURNAME = "SMITH", .DOB = New DateTime(1995, 5, 5), .AGE = 31 },
        New CONTACTS() With { .FIRST_NAME = "ABIGAIL", .SURNAME = "SMITH", .DOB = New DateTime(1995, 5, 5), .AGE = 31 }
    })

    Console.WriteLine(dctCONTACTS(2)(0).FIRST_NAME)

End Sub
```

Running `TEST_DICT` gives `BOB` in this case.

Comment: tks, I did an online search and found nothing

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but what about [Google Learn VB.NET](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=learn+vb.net)?

Comment: I'd like to answer your comment in a chat, is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how to force the creation of a chat. It's probably easiest just to answer here.

Comment: ok, I'm in the process of converting an options model from vba to vb.net and mainly need to know how to manipulate databases in vb.net (or c#). I've bought a couple of books, download several more and lots of online searches, but nothing answers specific syntax or method queries like SO. Can you suggest a decent book or course?

Comment: I'm sorry, but of all of the topics available online, data access is probably the most prevalent. I really can't think where I'd go to start learning this stuff. Maybe try downloading some of Microsoft reference apps and looking at them. Otherwise look online for Entity Framework tutorials perhaps. There's heaps and heaps.

Comment: tks I'll take a look. 2 months ago I didn't know anything about .net or databases so I'll get there eventually

Comment: The school of hard knocks is probably the best. Can I ask how old you are?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103404/discussion-between-zeus-and-enigmativity).